# Section divider in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Is there a section divider in Spyder that is similar to R's '`--`'? Using '`--`' in R script automatically divide codes in different sections. One can find different sections, especially if the code is long. I wonder if there is a similar feature in Spyder.

Currently, I'm just using """ or ## such as

```
"""
Created on Mon Feb 11 11:24:15 2019

"""
```

or

```
##Section 1
```

They do not divide code in sections.

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925458/what-is-outline-explorer-in-spyder/54925573#54925573)

Comment: Thank you. I also used #%%, but I have to execute all code in the block defined by #%%. I guess I need the divider to just divide the section instead of forcing me to run the code in the block every time I push the run button.

Comment: You can divide code as functions and call them.

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure how it works on R, but you can use lines that start with comments of the form:

```
# %%
```

Different parts of your code are separated by them and then you can run each section separately if you want.

Comment: Using # %% as section heading is making all the code lines below it a single cell and when I'm running a single line, it only gives the output from the final line. Is there another way to make it work?

Answer (score 15):

Here are some examples :

***Example 1 : One cell with navigable sections***

```
#%% Notes

#### Defining Code Cells
# A “code cell” in Spyder is a block of lines, typically in a script, that can be 
# easily executed all at once.
# You can separate cells by lines starting with either: 
# 1) #%% (standard cell separator)
# 2) # %% (standard cell separator, when file has been edited with Eclipse)
# 3) # <codecell> (IPython notebook cell separator)

#### Cell heirarchy
# To nest navigable sections within a cell, use "#### ~some heading~"
# To nest subcells within a cell, use "#%% >> #%%% >> #%%%% .... "
```

In Outline Explorer (Spyder) appears as:

```
File.py
  % Notes
    # Section 1
    # Section 2
```

***Example 2 : Cell with subcells***

```
#%% Main cell

#%%% Nested cell 1
#%%%% Nested(2) cell 1
#%%%% Nested(2) cell 2

#%%% Nested cell 2
```

Using this structure, the nested cells can be executed separately.

```
File.py
  % Main Cell
    % Nested cell 1
      % Nested(2) cell 1
      % Nested(2) cell 2
    % Nested cell 2
```